# How to tell if currently selected tab was pressed again?

Tags: ios, uitabbar

I would like to assign an action if the user attempts to select a currently selected tab.

For example, if tab 1 is selected and the user tries to select tab 1 again, I want to make my app do something.

Are there any UITabBarController methods that will intercept this attempt?

I've looked through `UITabBar`, `UITabBarController`, and `UITabBarItem` APIs and can't find anything obvious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to set a `UITabBarControllerDelegate`. Specifically the 
`- tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:` method where you can simply check `self.selectedViewController` against the view controller passed in. If they are the same, the selected is being selected again.